# Video shows first frame then plays from currenttime at every setting of currenttime

Tags: html5-video

I use more than one videos. When I set the video current time, First I see the first frame of the video than the video plays from current time. How can I get rid of that first frame
the code block where I set the video source and current time is here

```
v.src="videos/"+v_name+".webm";
    v.load();
    arc_time = arc_length / 20;
    dist = Math.abs(x-node_x[s_node-1]);
    v.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function()
    {
        v.currentTime = (v.duration/arc_length) * dist;
        v.playbackRate = v.duration / arc_time;
    });
    v.play();
```

To test my study in this link:
http://fbe.karabuk.edu.tr/gis/canvas1.php
- Push draw nodes and draw lines buttons
- Set starting point to 3
- Push right arrow several times